# R dismo randomPoints can't handle projected data?

Tags: r, coordinate-system

I'm trying to generate random points from a raster using randomPoints from dismo in R. However, when I overlay the points on top of the raster, it looks like the points aren't in the same projection as the raster:

```
r <- raster("C:/raster.tiff")
crs(r)



  CRS arguments:
     +proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80
    +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 

bg<-randomPoints(r,10000,p=preloc, ext=extent(r),lonlatCorrection = TRUE)
```

[image]

Is there any argument that I am missing to make this line up correctly?

Comment: If you plot vector data on top of a raster and resize the plot window this is often the result. Submit the plot commands again to see if things align. Perhaps there is an offset error introduced by the function. You could try raster::sampleRandom to cross-check results.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Thanks, as always your comments/answers are always insightful. I saved the plot and it aligns, I also tried plotting with rasterVis and it all lines up. This stumped me for longer than I care to admit....